# Why does my client Socket not connect to my ServerSocket?

Tags: java, windows, sockets, network-programming, serversocket

In this extremely basic client/server socket program, why does my client socket never connect and throw `java.net.ConnectException`? I am running the MessageServer program on one computer, and the ClientServer program on another laptop on the same network. I have verified that the local-ip of the computer which is running the server program is 10.0.0.1 using the ipconfig command in the windows cmd on that computer.

**Server:**

```
package server;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MessageServer {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4302);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("well bad news...");
        }

        boolean noConnection = true;
        while(noConnection == true) { 
            try {
                Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("socket connection accepted:" + client.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString());
                noConnection = false;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("fail");
            }

    }
    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

    public class MessageClient {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Socket clientSocket = null;
            String recieve;
            try {
                clientSocket = new Socket("10.0.0.1", 4302);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("deal with it...");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }
```

When I run these 2 programs, i get the following result on the client machine:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at MessageClient.main(MessageClient.java:10)
```

No issues on the server machine.

*EDIT:*
I tried disabling my internet security (Norton 360), didn't help. Also, I am running (on both computers) Windows 10, Java 8 Update 65, Eclipse IDE Mars 1

**EDIT 2:** 
In case it helps, I tried running both parts of the program on one computer, this works. All signs point to a windows firewall issue. I will try to get to this as soon as possible.

Comment: Most likely cause: Windows Firewall.

Comment: @HarryJohnston surprise, Microsoft windows screws me over. Oh wait, never mind.. =\.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I finally figured this problem out. Just putting this answer out there for anyone who runs into the same problem. When creating the client socket you need to directly specify the local ipv4 of the machine its connecting too. For some reason, local host will not allow it to connect and says the connection is refused for LAN connections. So EX Code:

```
Socket client = new Socket("10.0.0.8", 5566);
```

**instead of:**

```
Socket client = new Socket("localhost" 5566);
```

If you are looking for the ipv4, go on the server machine, open the CMD (windows), and type `ipconfig`. Then under `Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:` use the address listed under IPv4 Adress.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what is the local ip of your computer. You server is running on localhost and hence you need to connect to localhost.

Change this to

```
clientSocket = new Socket("10.0.0.1", 4302);
```

to

```
clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4302);
```

When you host your Server on a VPS then you can change the localhost to the IP of the VPS.

You can also use "127.0.0.1" in place of "localhost".

**EDIT**
According to the exception you are getting now,

The exception occurs when server is not listening on the port you are trying to connect to.

Either you have not started your server or server is not accepting connections or the port numbers on client and server are different.

**EDIT 2**

Since you are running Client and Server on different PC's (assuming different networks) you will need to port forward your Router to accept connections.

More about port forwarding [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding)

Additionally you can use this website for helping you with port forwarding. [Port Forwarding](http://portforward.com/)

Comment: yeah I figured that, I tried this earlier and it didnt work. Also just retried it to confirm, same result: net exception.

Comment: Add a  e.printStackTrace(); before you system print in server which says bad news to check whether the port is already in used. It may be the case that you are already using the port 4302. The program runs fine for me.

Comment: also, i tried running it on 3 different ports (5065, 10200, 8477)

Comment: okay, so, lets go through those one by one since I think I've met these requirements. When I want to run these programs, I first launch the server program on my pc, then once its open I launch the client program on my laptop. The port numbers are exactly the same. I dont know what you mean by the server is not accepting connections.

Comment: I do have Norton 360 installed on my desktop, I tried disabling that and then running the program. Still no luck. Could MS windows firewall be the problem? I have windows 10.

Comment: Check the edited answer. Since you have client and server on different systems you will require port forwarding.

Comment: Darn, that stinks. I had to do this once for Minecraft (yeah dont laugh). It was a pain in the behind. Although, I am a little surprised by that because I did this exact same thing (this being socket connections) in python 3 and it didn't require any port forwarding. Plus, I didn't think port forwarding was nescesarry for LAN projects.

Comment: You can also get a cheap VPS and host the server there and then connect. Anyway I hope I pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: You shouldn't need port forwarding. Do try disabling the Windows firewall on both systems, as well as any anti-virus/internet security on both systems. That will often fix issues of this sort, assuming both computers are on the same LAN.

Comment: @Sneh not really an option, especially since I'm just doing this all for fun.

Comment: @JoelC yeah that was my next move, let me give that a shot and I will let you know how that went. Although the whole damn turning off security business makes me nervous.

Comment: @JoelC I didn't know that. Thanks. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @JoelC I'm about to loose it in a minute, cant even turn off my windows firewall because its being managed by Norton 360. This is going to take some time I imagine, I will try to get back to you as soon as possible, thanks for the sugestion, I will look into this.

Comment: Do also try reversing which computer is the server and which is the client. Also, once the server code is running run `netstat -anp tcp` on the server computer. You should see a LISTENING line with your server's port number. If you don't, something is wrong.

Comment: @JoelC ok thanks will do, currently on the go right now but when I get back I'll give it a shot.

Comment: You don't need to turn the firewall off.  Just create an exception.

Comment: True, but turning the firewall off will at least give an indication of whether or not that is the issue.

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code. The part about 'server is not accepting connections' is incorrect.

Comment: @JoelC: ordinarily, yes.  But if you have to fight with your security software in order to do so, the effort involved may be disproportionate.

Comment: @JoelC yes, I do see listening under the port number of my server when I run the server-program. Im going to try the firewall thing as soon as I finish my HW.

Comment: One other thing to try is to telnet to the port from the server computer itself and from the client computer. This will help determine if it's an issue with the networking or the programs.

Comment: @JoelC I'm guessing this is a network issue. I tried running the 2 programs on the same machine (see post edit), this worked just fine. I will try to edit the firewall settings when I get a chance (busy during weekdays). Also, thanks for that `netstat` command, that will come in handy.