# communicate between different network using java socket

Tags: java, sockets, networking, mqtt, node-red

I've created a java chat application using java socket. It can communicate in local network, but if I use another network it doesn't work. I've tried by using public IP but it still not connected. 
The chat application has a serverGUI and clientGUI so, I've started the serverGUI on PC by using its public IP. And then I've connected my Laptop connected in another network and tried to connect to the server by entering the PC's public IP but it not connected.

I've been also told to use MQTT, but I haven't found a useful tutorial about it.
I'm using MQTT Paho and use Node-Red

Please help me to get communicated over different networks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33468332/why-does-my-client-socket-not-connect-to-my-serversocket

Comment: You most likely need to set up port-forwarding on the router to your server or disable or reconfigure the firewall on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution with MQTT would be using a public MQTT broker (server) and let your clients connect to it.

Just to name a couple of them: **test.mosquitto.org**, **iot.eclipse.org**.
Be careful that messages will be *public*, i.e. anyone could read them.

Both your clients should be able to connect, this is an example on how to do it with Paho MQTT client in Java.

```
String broker = "tcp://iot.eclipse.org:1883";
client = new MqttClient(broker, "javachatclientid1", new MemoryPersistence());
client.setCallback(m_callbackHandler);
MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
connOpts.setCleanSession(true);
connOpts.setUserName("username");
connOpts.setPassword("password");
client.connect(connOpts);
```

Your applications must use a different clientId. You should then use a unique topic structure, for example publish your messages under `your/java/package/chat/<roomname>/msg/<username>/`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a router between the networks and NAT behind it, make sure you route the connection on the port you want to the servers internal IP address.

For example:

My external IP is 8.8.8.8 and I want to connect to port 65565.
The internal IP is 192.168.0.10 waiting for a connection 65565.
On your router, port forward every request from the external IP for port 65565 to 192.168.0.10.

Comment: Your external IP is Google's DNS?:)

Comment: IP off the top of my head. :)

Comment: Port number is **< 65536**

Comment: Hey, i voted you. Do yo know how to do what you said? How can i open the port and forward it to my server?